# Unity Editor - stuck at building native binary with IL2CPP

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have an Unity project and planning to embed it in Android studio as a library. I followed https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a on how to do that. When building the unity project, im stuck at building native binary with IL2CPP in the unity editor. What is wrong here? :(

Comment: Is there any error message when building?

Comment: When you say stuck... to give you an idea, I have a reasonable spec laptop, but not epic.  what took 5.5 mins to compile on my home PC took 5.5 HOURS on my work laptop due to lack of spec.. so "stuck" how is it stuck...

Comment: @aalmighty im outside now, will post the error message when i got home. thanks in advance.

Comment: @BugFinder im pretty sure its not about the spec of my pc cause my setup is quite high end. Also if i build the project without using IL2CPP scripting backend, it works just fine. What i mean stuck is the loading bar does not move and the unity editor not responding. The only way to close it is by using task manager. But this happens only if i build with IL2CPP scripting enabled.

Comment: thats exactly how mine reacted though @UmarFaizDaniel, mine sat there 5.5 hours - the iL2CPP processes were slowed a lot by some things on the machine, av, file access logging etc.  And while I could see in task manager the many il2cpp processes coming and going and that there were the same amount at any given time as my home PC.. the work PC took 5.5 hours first build, home pc 5.5 mins, but they didnt seem to be slowed when looking in task manager. it seems the il2cpp is quite process hungry in terms of many start/stops

Comment: Guys i solved the issue. It has something to do with Android TV support. I am using Vuforia which does not support Android TV. I disabled the Android TV support in Unity and it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have found solution for this. If you are using Visual Studio for Unity, you just need to install "**Desktop development with c++**" module to it. You can install it by Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure how, but this solved the issue for me:

- Windows Key + R
- Type in "regedit"

Do this while it is stuck and it should start working again.